# How to set and get the id for the items in the spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem like I had a Spinner containing the Names of all developers working in the Company.
I have used the `ArrayAdapter` with a Array having the names of all the **developers** which is fetched from the database.

The problem is that when I update the Name Of Developer field, I get Only the Name of the Developer which is not enough to update the data as their can be multiple developers with the same name in the Company.
So now I require the id of the developers to update it..
How to store that **id** of the developers with the `Spinner` so that I can achieve this.

For example, I want to do like is as that we do in `HTML`::

    `<select>

    <option id="1">Developer1</option>

    <option id="2">Developer2</option>

    <option id="3">Developer2</option>

    <option id="4">Developer2</option>

    </select>`

where the **id** attached would be the database **id**.
I want to imitate this in android.

This the code that I have used to store the names in the array::

```
String alldevelopers = null;
try 
{
  ArrayList<NameValuePair> postP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  alldevelopers = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("/fetchdevelopers.php", postP);
  String respcl = alldevelopers.toString();
  alldevelopersParser dev = new alldevelopersParser();
  ow = dev.parseByDOM(respcl);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}  

String developers[] = new String[ow.length];    //dev is a class object  
for (int n = 0; n < ow.length; n++)   
{  
  developers[n] = ow.developer[n][2];
}
```

This is the Spinner that would spin the array..

```
final Spinner devl = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.towner);  
devl.setOnItemSelectedListener(managetasks.this);
ArrayAdapter<String> b =   
new ArrayAdapter<String>getApplicationContext(),  
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,developers);  
b.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);  
devl.setAdapter(b);
```

Comment: A question: the spinner is loaded with developer names taken in the same order as into the database? It might be useful to consider the position of the item within the spinner, to determine, for the same position, the id of the programmer in the db?

Comment: Yes...the order of loading would be the same as that of the database...but then the id of the developers would not be in the increment way as if some of the developers are deleted then the their id would be missing in the list...so we can't compare the itemSelected position directly with that of the id in the database...Is their any other way my dear friend that wouldsearch the database on the basis of the ItemSelectedposition number..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform setOnItemSelectedListener on the spinner then you have method such as

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {}
```

here you can findout the position of selected developer name of spinner and use this position to fetch data from array.

Comment: Jitender...you are right but then how would i compare in the database?? Only i can get by this is the position and the value displayed...is their any way in which i could attach the database id of the developer with the spinner so that when i fetch the value from the spinner, i could get the database id  attached with that fetched item..??

Comment: When you fetch the whole record of project in arrayList<Project> or any collection then you can get the whole object from that position from arrayList of collection. If u still have problem please share you code.