# Reading input from spinner

Tags: android, spinner

How do I get input from a spinner. I have three option which are words. I want to assign a number for each one so I can do a calculation. Like option hat = 5 and toy =  10. Then have my math problem look to see what the user selected and substitute it with a number value.

Edit:
1. Look at spinner 1 input.
2. Assign string with a number value.
3. Insert string into math problem.

Sorry hope this explain it a little better.

Comment: Could you share the code you tried?

Comment: I can't find any example to figure it out.

Comment: Please check this Question Of mine...might help you to figure out the Solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954093/how-to-set-and-get-the-id-for-the-items-in-the-spinner-containing-the-names-of-t

Comment: your spinner input is static or dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string array where hat, toy etc will be stored and also can create another int array where value's corresponding that string array will be stored. Now display the string array in spinner and then add item selected listener on that spinner to get which string name is touched from where you get the item no and then fetch the value from the int array. i think this will do.

```
String[] item_name  = {"hat","toy"};
int[] item_value  = {5,10};

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, item_name);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Event Listener Will be Like

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item_name[arg2]+"|"+item_value[arg2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```